# Conditional Rendering in JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

How can I do a conditional rendering with JSX?

for instance I have div here where I want to render the text "NO IDEA" if the value of the props in null otherwise render the props if its not equal to null.

For example:

```
<div>{ return this.props.date === null ? 'NO IDEA' : this.props.date }</div>
```

I tried this but it did not worked out. Any idea what am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't need a `return` there. This is covered in the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-else-with-conditional-operator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can simply use ternary operator based on this.props.date so you do not need return here

```
<div> {this.props.date === null ? 'NO IDEA' : this.props.date }</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you don't need to use `return` statement inside the expression block. Next thing, don't check just for `null`, it might be `undefined` rather:

```
<div>{ this.props.date ? this.props.date : 'NO IDEA' }</div>
```

This simply checks if `date` is available / true parsed in boolean,  then use true value else use false value.

Or, even in simpler syntax using `||`:

```
{ this.props.date || 'NO IDEA' }
```

This will render the date only if date value is true parsed in boolean otherwise it will render 'NO IDEA'.

Comment: IMO whether or not an explicit `null` check is appropriate is app-dependent; not for us to decide or dictate. But if you're going to, why not just `{ this.props.date || 'NO IDEA' }`?

Comment: Yes, and what I'm saying is that whether or not doing an explicit check is a good idea depends on the app.

Comment: The answer is valid. All I'm saying is that giving advice to do an implicit comparison it outside the scope of the question, and may not fit the needs of the OP.